# Django ORM simple Join

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I want to perform simple join operation like this.

raw SQL :  **select * from risks r join sku_details s on r.sku_id = s.sku_id;**

model Details:

```
class SkuDetails(models.Model):
    sku_id = models.DecimalField(primary_key=True, max_digits=65535, decimal_places=65535)
    sku_desc = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    category = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)



class Risks(models.Model):
    risk_id = models.DecimalField(primary_key=True, max_digits=65535, decimal_places=65535)
    risk_group_short_desc = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    risk_group_desc = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    var = models.DecimalField(max_digits=65535, decimal_places=65535, blank=True, null=True)
    sku = models.ForeignKey(SkuDetails, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
```

After joining I want all the column of both the table in flat structure through Django ORM... 
In raw SQL I will get all the column ... But not getting from ORM

Please Help !!!

Comment: You don't actually want this. The whole point of using an ORM is that it gives you objects, not lists of values.

Answer (score 1):

Getting all values in a list of dictionaries is quite easy with [values()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#values):

```
Risks.objects.values(
    'risk_id',
    'risk_group_short_desc`,
    # ... fields you need from Risks
    'sku__sku_id',
    # ... fields you need from SkuDetails
)
```

You can check out [values_list()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) as well.

Comment: Is there are way ... I dont have to add all the column ... By default it will give me all the related column in object.?

Comment: Not if you need related fields I believe. `values()` without parameters gives you all fields, but only in the queried model.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with`select_related`. Relevant helping [material](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/833793/Use-of-select-related-method-in-Django) As both model with foreign-key relation.

Comment: with select_related .. in am getting nested result ... i want flat result.
Is there any method to get that ?

Comment: then @NikunjAggarwal you need to go with `value_list` what just @Endre Both said.